# updateOrCreate with increment in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, illuminate-container

What I am trying to do is to update or insert the row in table. In my case, update looks something like this:

```
\DB::table('inventories')->where('product_code',$product_code)->increment('stock_current_quantity',$quantity);
```

I don't want to use if else statement. What I actually want is to integrate increment into following statement so it update as above statement.

```
 \App\Inventory::updateOrCreate(['product_code' => $product_code], ['stock_current_quantity'=>$quantity]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you are not using the Eloquent? It's so easy with Eloquent Model.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not do:

```php
$inventory = \App\Inventory::firstOrNew(['product_code' => $product_code]);

$inventory->stock_current_quantity = ($inventory->stock_current_quantity + $quantity);
$inventory->save();
```

If the model doesn't exists, `$inventory->stock_current_quantity` will only be equal to `$quantity`, else, it will increment it by `$quantity`.

Comment: There's a small risk that the database `stock_current_quantity` might change in between retrieving the item and saving it though. That's why `increment` is safer to use

Comment: Yup. There's that. If that's a concern and `product_code` is a unique index and MySQL is the only DBMS used, perhaps an `insert ... on duplicate key update` statement is more appropriate.

Comment: this may cause raise conditions. Its better to use tomstig's method

Answer (score 26):

Because google brought me here and I think the answers here, especially when you simply want to use updateOrCreate, are not as satisfying as this:

```
\App\Inventory::updateOrCreate([
         'product_code' => $product_code
    ], 
    [
         'stock_current_quantity' => \DB::raw('stock_current_quantity + 1')
    ]
);
```

Credits to [this guy](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/using-updateorcreate-with-incrementing-value?page=1#reply=401514)

Comment: if you use these code ,you can get an error like this: Eloquent update with DB::raw triggers Object of class Illuminate/Database/Query/Expression could not be converted to int

Comment: It doesn't work at create (actually `INSERT`) because the field `stock_current_quantity` is not yet set.

Answer (score 13):

I am using Laravel 7.8.1 and rolling it all into one statement as per the following works fine:

```
    $user->league_entries()->updateOrCreate([
        'month' => $month,
        'year' => $year
    ])->increment('score');
```

Comment: Can you get the model `id` from this query ?

Comment: I believe the statement above just returns a `true` value.

Answer (score 1):

just contributing if someone else has this problem

it doesn't exist, creates, but with zero

```
self::firstOrNew(['product_code' => $product_code]);
```

then, increment it... if other process updates it to 1 before me (in this middle time between firstOrNew and increment), this will update to 2, avoiding losing the prior update

```
self::where('product_code', $product_code)->increment('stock_current_quantity');
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Inigo's answer, but slight change i would go with:

```php
 $user->league_entries()->firstOrCreate([
        'month' => $month,
        'year' => $year
    ])->increment('score');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model::updateOrInsert([
 "name" => "last_run21",
 ], [
 "value" => DB::raw("IF(ISNULL(value + 1),1,value+1)"),
]);
```

This basically either creates the entry with name == "last_run21" with a initial value of 1 or updates it with value+1.

Tested on Mysql.

Comment: In order to use the `Model` directly, you need to adjust the namespace on the top.